# Accessing and searching data from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, search

If I have the JSON object below

```
 {
    "animals":{     
        "a_1":{    
        "species":"Tiger",     
        "name":"Timmy",     
        "dob":"2016-03-12",       
        },    
        "a_2":{    
        "species":"Lion",     
        "name":"Leo",     
        "dob":"2012-12-04",           
        }   
    }    
}
```

How do I search to return

```
"a_1": {    
    "species":"Tiger",     
    "name":"Timmy",     
    "dob":"2016-03-12",       
},
```

for the search `a_1`?

Is there a similar way to call `a_1`/ `a_2`, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly search by Key.

For example:

```
var data = {
    "animals":{     
        "a_1":{    
            "species":"Tiger",     
            "name":"Timmy",     
            "dob":"2016-03-12",       
        },    
        "a_2":{    
            "species":"Lion",     
            "name":"Leo",     
            "dob":"2012-12-04",           
        }   
    }    
};

var searchKey = "a_1";
console.log(data["animals"][searchKey]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Only trouble is I keep getting this error "Cannot read property 'searchKey' of undefined", however searchKey is defined

Comment: My info is in a separate JSON file so I have:

    fs.readFile('animals.json', 'utf8', function (err, data){
  var dataS = JSON.parse(data);

which I thought would do the same job?

Comment: Sorted, problem with my earlier script. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your data structure to an array. It would be easier:

```js
const data = {
  "animals": {
    "a_1": {
      "species": "Tiger",
      "name": "Timmy",
      "dob": "2016-03-12",
    },
    "a_2": {
      "species": "Lion",
      "name": "Leo",
      "dob": "2012-12-04",
    }
  }
}
const animalList = Object.keys(data.animals).map(key => ({
  key,
  item: data.animals[key]
}))
const searchName = input => animalList.filter(animal => animal.item.name === input);
console.log(searchName('Leo'))
```

Comment: ...and where exactly is the array in your data structure?

Comment: animalList is the conversion of your serialized JSON object into an array !

Comment: `you should change your data structure to an array`, I understood that you didn't change the data structure to an array. It's still an object

Comment: animalList is an array and the search is processed against that array